# tool for logging all actions happening i browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, logging

I am wondering if there is a developer tool out their, either in the browser, or a external tool.

That can log all actions happening one a web page, with scripts and css. Like when you hit a button, which scripts are being fired and what they do?

Comment: ... hit f12 on your keyboard

Comment: yeah then the developer tool comes up, but that will not give you all actions happening on the site, when click on a button, input field, or a menu?

Comment: ... timeline recording? you need to press the record button you know.

Comment: Yes thank that seemd to be the right, if you submit that as a answer i will tag it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press F12 on the page you wish to analyze.
Then press the record button on the timeline tab of the developper tools